# Will a thread in a while loop give CPU time to another thread of same type?

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop

If I have the following dummy code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  TestRunnable test1 = new TestRunnable();
  TestRunnable test2 = new TestRunnable();
  Thread thread1 = new Thread(test1);
  Thread thread2 = new Thread(test2);
  thread1.start();
  thread2.start();
}

public static class TestRunnable implements Runnable {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    while(true) {
      //bla bla
    }
  }
}
```

In my current program I have a similar structure i.e. two threads executing the same Run() method. But for some reason only thread 1 is given CPU time i.e. thread 2 never gets a chance to run. Is this because while thread 1 is in its while loop , thread 2 waits?

I'm not exactly sure, if a thread is in a while loop is it "blocking" other threads? I would think so, but not 100% sure so it would be nice to know if anyone could inform me of what actually is happening here.

**EDIT**
Okay, just tried to make a really simple example again and now both threads are getting CPU time. However this is not the case in my original program. Must be some bug somewhere. Looking into that now. Thanks to everyone for clearing it up, at least I got that knowledge.

Comment: Works for me running `JavaSE-1.7`. Are you using 1.7 or 1.6?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no guarantee by the JVM that it will halt a busy thread to give other threads some CPU.

It's good practice to call `Thread.yield();`, or if that doesn't work call `Thread.sleep(100);`, inside your busy loop to let other threads have some CPU.

Comment: I do have the thread sleeping for 5 seconds, even tried for 20 seconds, but thread 2 is still not allowed inside it's while loop despite both threads running the same run() method?

Comment: does the JVM truly handle CPU usage? Isn't this always given to the OS to handle?

Comment: @Jatt I find that hard to believe. Edit your question and add in all the (relevant) code in your while loop to show us what you're doing.

Comment: Most modern JVMs have complex algorithms which properly give the different threads in the run queue time slices.  My experience is the `Thread.yield()` is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

At some point a modern operating system will [*preempt*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29) the current context and switch to another thread - however, it *will* also (being a rather dumb thing overall) turn the CPU into a toaster: this small "busy loop" could be computing a checksum, and it would be a shame to make that run slow!

For this reason, it is often advisable to `sleep/yield` manually - even `sleep(0)`<sup>1</sup> - which will *yield* execution of the thread before the OS decides to *take* control. In practice, for the given empty-loop code, this would result in a change from 99% CPU usage to 0% CPU usage when yielding manually. (Actual figures will vary based on the "work" that is done each loop, etc.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The minimum time of yielding a thread/context varies based on OS and configuration which is why it isn't always desirable to yield - but then again Java and "real-time" generally don't go in the same sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The actual thread scheduling should be handled by the OS and not Java. This means that each Thread should be given equal running time (although not in a predictable order). In your example, each thread will spin and do nothing while it is active. You can actually see this happening if inside the while loop you do `System.out.println(this.toString())`. You should see each thread printing itself out while it can.

Why do you think one thread is dominating?

Comment: The reason I think it is, is because before anything is executed inside of the while loop, I have the thread name being printed out. And for every iteration of the while loop it's only thread 1 printing itself out. Thread2 never gets to enter the while loop, even though they run the same run() method. That's what I don't get. The answer you have provided is exactly my understanding of how it works. But then this is confusing me

Answer (score 0):

The OS is responsible for scheduling the thread. That was changed in couple of years ago. It different between different OS (Windows/Linux etc..) and it depends heavily on the number of CPUs and the code running. If the code does not include some waiting functionality like Thread.yield() or synchhonized block with a wait() method on the monitor, it's likely that the CPU will keep the thread running for a long time. 
Having a machine with multiple CPUs will improve your parallelism of your application but it's a bad programming to write a code inside a run() method of a thread that doesn't let other thread to run in a multi-threaded environment.